# Webhook listener with csrf

Tags: django, security, csrf

I want to create a webhook listener for a third party app. But fot this i have to use @csrf_exempt .
Without using the above my web app isn't allowing the third party app to send the webhook data. It blocks it and says forbidden.

My question is if we do it without the csrf token can it cause a security vulnerability? What are the other ways to handle this securely.

Comment: Are you doing with it jQuery? Yes, it can cause security issue, you can see more in the docs.

Comment: The webhook API you are using should provide you a way to verify the request (e.g., by including a signed header that you can verify against a secret key) - that is how you ensure that you only accept requests from the third party app. Disabling CSRF is necessary for webhooks.